# How can I set up nginx to solve 404 not found on static file vue?

Tags: vue.js, nginx, vue-component, vuetify.js, static-files

I using nginx to run my project. So I install nginx to my localhost to testing it

My configuration nginx on localhost like this :

```
location / {
    root   html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

If I refresh a page, it exist error like this :

```
404 Not Found
nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
```

I search on google and I get some reference. I try like this :

```
location / {
    root /www/dist;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

I works. There is no error

Then I deploy my project to production

My configuration nginx on production like this :

```
location / {
    root /www/dist;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

It works too

But my problem is I need to change the location to be like this :

```
location /startup {
    root /www/dist;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

I have a lot of projects in the nginx. So I have to add `/startup` to show that it's startup project. But it makes error like this :

```
404 Not Found
nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Check out [this documentation issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/2863) and [the resulting change](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `root` in nginx, it always *appends* the route to the end of the file path but that's not obvious when using `/`.  So in your first examples with `location /`, it searches for this path on the server:

```
root + /www/dist + /
```

But when you use `location /startup`, it looks for this path which does not exist:

```
root + /www/dist + /startup
```

So to use both `root` and "/startup", you would need a directory called "startup". 
 But, you can use alias.  Try this:

```
location /startup {
    alias /www/dist;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /startup/index.html;
}
```

The [Vue Router docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations) recommend something similar to this as well.  (But they don't show how to use a subfolder `alias`.)

Comment: I try like this : `location /startup/ {
    alias /www/dist;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}`. But it does not works. It's the same

Comment: I use `try_files` to solve `404 Not Found`. If I don't use it, seems it does not works

Comment: What is your full root path?  I'll change my answer to something else to try.

Comment: What do you mean full root path? This : `Macintosh HD/www/dist`?

Comment: Oh ok, so `www` is top level.  I edited my answer with something you can try

Comment: I try to access `http://localhost/startup`, there appears a blank page

Comment: Then you probably forgot to set `publicPath` in your Vue config.  See this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60331499/vue-adds-to-path-css-and-js-not-visible/60332120#60332120.  Where it says `/path/to/folder/`, put `/startup/`.  You will need to rebuild your project too.

Comment: I had try it on my localhost and it works. But later I will try that on a production server. If it works i will accept your answer

Comment: Hi. I want to ask. Why use  `alias`? I read here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631933/nginx-static-file-serving-confusion-with-root-alias. using `root` is better than `alias`

Comment: Which answer says `root` is better?  What does it say is better about it?  `alias` is the one that does what you asked.  If you prefer `root` instead, you can do that, you just need to use an actual path to a folder named `startup`.  My answer also mentions how to do that.

Comment: You are great. Thanks  a lot :)

Comment: Anything good in me is God's doing, thanks for your encouragement.  I linked the Vue Router docs and adjusted the answer slightly to match the way the docs suggest, using `alias`.

Comment: Okay. So which is the best solution? Using `alias`?

Comment: Yes, still alias.  The only difference now is using both `$uri $uri/` instead of just `$uri`

Comment: @Dan I'm running into a similar issue. I want to serve thumbnails from nginx to vue. My paths on the frontend look like `<img class="thumbnail" :src="'http://localhost:8000/thumbnail/'+m.name">` and my server block route looks like `location /thumbnail/ { alias /opt/myapp/static/img/thumbnail/; }`. But I keep getting the broken image icon. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Soubriquet - It's probably best to ask a new question and provide all relevant information.